# Convert string into jQuery object and add attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<label>Lobby Template:</label>
```

I want to convert it to jquery object and add an attribute id with  a value of test:

```
<label id="test">Lobby Template:</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $el = $('<label>Lobby Template:</label>').attr('id', 'test');
```

Answer (score 2):

I like this syntax:

```
var $el = $("<label>", {
    id: "test",
    text: "Lobby Template:"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery **`attr`**

```
$('label').attr('id', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('label')[0].id="test";
```

You need to have some sort of hook to identify your element. http://jsfiddle.net/RQ3vH/1/ is a demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
$('label').attr('id','test');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels = $('label')
$.each(labels, function(i, label){
    if($(label).html() == 'Lobby Template:' ){
    $(label).attr("id", "test")
    }
})
```